# Scrolling text for narrative in web adventure game

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, text, scroll

I can not seem to get the exact effect I want.  Basically I would like the text to scroll up from the bottom of the text area, then once the bottom of the text entry has scrolled into view stop scrolling.  The text entry MAY be longer than the text field, so I would like the user to be able to scroll through the text if they want.

I have played around with marquee and JavaScript, but have not been able to get the desired effect.  I would prefer to stay away from third party plugins, party to learn this for myself, and partly so I don't have to worry about future support.

So can anyone give me some pointers on how to setup this up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can animate a div..

```
var c = $("#container");
    var SPEED = 10000;
    var thediv = $("#mydiv");
    thediv.show()
    thediv.animate({
        top: c.height() - thediv.height() - 10},
        SPEED, 
        function () {
            thediv.css("height", c.height());
            thediv.css("top", 0);        
            var objDiv = document.getElementById("mydiv");
            objDiv.scrollTop = objDiv.scrollHeight;
    });
```

You'll want to mess around with the formatting some...here's a fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/kmd97/DmkMZ/